# Clojure: Meaning of ::tag

Tags: clojure

Recently I met construction like `{::tag 10}` in Clojure. What does it mean? My experiments showed up that it's a keyword to:

```
=> (type :tag)
clojure.lang.Keyword
=> (type ::tag)
clojure.lang.Keyword
```

The difference is value itself:

```
=> :tag
:tag
=> ::tag
:/user/tag
```

Seems like `::tag` is namespace qualified. Is it right guess? If yes, what the difference between namespace qualified keyword and non-qualified? When it can be useful?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The double-colon is the shorthand syntax for a namespace qualified keyword, with the current namespace. It is ideal for preventing collisions with external keyword based keys in hash-maps, such as having a :name and a ::name key in function metadata or comparing the :name vs ::name value of a parameter.

Just like you would namespace a public function to both identify it and prevent name conflicts, when exposing a custom keyword as a key or a value, that could conflict would existing keywords, you should consider namespace qualifying it.

Comment: So is it shorthand for :my-current-namespace/keyword ?

Comment: Yes. The current namespace will be used to namespace the keyword.